# How to disable Mega Menu on Magento2 Porto theme

Tags: php, frontend, backend, html, design

I have one CMS page and I would like to disable the mega menu on it, but not the other pages?
How can I do this?
and I want to disable the buttons that I mention in the picture attached.
Many Thanks!
[image: the mega menu and buttons that I want to remove]

Answer (score 0):

To remove menu, you need to added following code into the particular CMS Page layout section.

```
<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
```

Comment: could you please explain (the particular CMS Page layout section) where can i find this file.
and i want  to display this from just one page not all pages.

Comment: You can found that on admin side where you can add/Edit CMS page.